# Is it possible to check the value of defined statement using C preprocessor?

Tags: c-preprocessor

Let's say I have a `#define RTR r2` statement. Is it possible to check the **value** of the `RTR` macro? I'm looking something like this:

```
#if RTR == r1 || RTR == r2
It is router1 or router2!
#endif
```

I guess this is not possible..

Comment: Have a read here https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html#If

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's have a look at [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html):

> [In '#if'] *expression* is a C expression of integer type, subject to stringent  restrictions. It may contain
>
> - [...]
> - Macros. All macros in the expression are expanded before actual computation of the expression's value begins.
>     Uses of the defined operator, which lets you check whether macros are defined in the middle of an ‘#if’.
> - Identifiers that are not macros, which are all considered to be the number zero. This allows you to write #if MACRO instead of #ifdef MACRO, if you know that MACRO, when defined, will always have a nonzero value. Function-like macros used without their function call parentheses are also treated as zero.

So, according to the last point, unless `r1` ans `r2` are macros (or integer constants) themselves in your example, condition

```
#if RTR == r1 || RTR == r2
```

is equivalent to

```
#if RTR == 0 || RTR == 0
```

which I guess isn't the desired behaviour. For this to work you should assign `RTR` an integer constant value (or a expression, evaluating to integer constant at compile-time).

BTW, you should be very careful when giving a preprocessor macro such a short name as `RTR`, as it's very easy to clash with something.